# Trying to figure out an issue with corrupted stack while adding int arrays in c++

Tags: c++

I am working on visual studio 2013, with a windows8 hp.My code is trying to add two int arrays of size [20] and output the sum. I know I am out or range some where ,but I can't seem to find where. I am the first digit from each array during my convert function and my answer[i] output is only 19 digits when it should be 21digits.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstring>

using namespace   std;

int globalnum[20];

int total[21];
int i;
void convert(char[], int);
void add(int[], int[], int);
void printAnswer(int[], int);
int   main()
{
   char n1[20];
   char n2[20];
   int num1[20];
   int num2[20];
   int answer[21];

   cin >> n1 >> n2;
   int l1 = strlen(n1);
   int l2 = strlen(n2);
   int  max = fmax(l1, l2);

   convert(n1, l1);
   for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
      num1[i] = globalnum[i];
   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
      cout << num1[i];
   cout << endl;


   convert(n2, l2);
   for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
      num2[i] = globalnum[i];
   for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
      cout << num2[i];
   cout << endl;


   add(num1, num2, max);
   for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
      answer[i] = total[i];
   //  printAnswer(answer,max);
   for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
      cout << answer[i];
   return 0;
}
void convert(char c1[], int size)
{

   for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
      globalnum[i] = c1[size - 1 - i] - '0';

}
void  add(int add1[], int  add2[], int s1)
{
   int  sum[21];
   int remain = 0;

   for (i = 0; i < s1 - 1; i++)// This starts to add the numbers.
   {

      sum[i] = (add1[s1 - 1 - i] + add2[s1 - 1 - i] + remain) % 10;

      if (add1[s1 - 1 - i] + add2[s1 - 1 - i] + remain >= 10)
         remain = 1;
      else
         remain = 0;
      if (remain != 0)
         total[s1 - 1 - i] = 1;
      else total[s1 - 1 - i] = 0;

      total[s1 - 1 - i] = sum[i];

   }
   if (remain != 0)
      total[0] = 1;
}



//void printAnswer(int t[], int b)
// {
//  for (int i = b - 1; i < 0; i--)

//       cout << t[i];

//   }
//   cout << endl;
//}
```

Comment: What input are you using?

Comment: fmax() expects doubles as arguments, and returns a double. why are you using it on ints?

Comment: I think probably because he declares a variable called `max` and so hides the ordinary `std::max()` function...

Comment: Visual Studio has arguably the finest debugger for the Windows platform on planet-earth. I would strongly suggest using it, as it should make short work of this.

Comment: You are using C-style character arrays as string. *Stop that*. Use C++, use `std::string`.

Comment: There can be correct reasons and good ways to use char* in C++, but here are none. As suggested : use std::string and use your debugger.

Comment: [Some advice on debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm sorry first time user. I was assigned to input a string of numbers up to 20 digits. Then convert them to an int array using a function. then output the sum from another function.

Comment: You mean two strings of numbers?

Comment: Yes I meant two strings.  Thanks I'm going to learn to debug, then I'll check back.

Comment: If you are entering a 20 digit string, n1 and n2 need to be sized to 21 to have room for the null terminator.

Comment: I'm trying to get the hang of debugging. So far I get this error

Comment: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'n1' was corrupted.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 0):

There's too many problems with your code to give a simple answer. It's maybe easier to work backwards from working code. You haven't fully specified the problem but this was my best guess at what you're trying to do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> toInts(const string& s) {
    vector<int> v(s.size());
    transform(cbegin(s), cend(s), begin(v), [](int c) { return c - '0'; });
    return v;
}

int main() {
    string a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    auto n = toInts(a);
    auto m = toInts(b);
    const auto size = max(n.size(), m.size());
    n.resize(size);
    m.resize(size);
    vector<int> sums(size);
    transform(cbegin(n), cend(n), cbegin(m), begin(sums), plus<>{});
    copy(cbegin(sums), cend(sums), ostream_iterator<int>{cout, ", "});
    cout << endl;
}
```